# Quick boot but 25s from login to desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, secure-boot

I recently bought a PC with Windows and set up a dual boot with Ubuntu and grub as a boot loader. Then I started looking for a way to customize grub and ended up setting up Refind. I ran into some issues and disabled secure boot to fix them.

Everything works fine on Windows, but on Ubuntu, I get a long waiting period right after I login (more or less 25 seconds).

Here is a link to a gitlab snippet containing a few logs of those 25 seconds. https://gitlab.com/snippets/1905052

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause on [another forum](https://www.cnet.com/forums/post/8caef0c9-d929-4396-96d5-8b88b7b4de34/), it was the nouveau display driver. I changed to the proprietary Nvidia one, that fixed it.

Comment: Please add the solution, and use the link as reference only